# Array.From() different results

Tags: javascript, arrays

if you run this javascript on this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from 
you get the following result:

```
console.log(Array.from([1, 2, 3], x => x + x));
// expected output: Array [2, 4, 6]
> Array [2, 4, 6]
```

if you run the same code in the chrome console on this page(https://portal.fellowshipone.com/) i get this result:

```
console.log(Array.from([1, 2, 3], x => x + x));
// expected output: Array [2, 4, 6]

VM2786:1 (3) [1, 2, 3]
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: Normally it doesn't. Running this in both regular and "canary" Chrome results in [2,4,6]. So if you want to know what's up, investigate what `Array.from` is on that page by logging its toString. It's supposed to say something like "[native code]". Instead, you will discover that website shows something wildly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to is using [`Array.from`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/from/) from the Prototype library. Try to enter `Array.from` to the console and you will see that this function is declared in an external library which overrides [native implementation](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/from/).